# Convertir hora a milisegundos y sumar a otra hora

Tags: java

Tengo 2 horas que sumar y guardarlas en un atributo Long llamado duración, por lo que hago:

```
    String source1 = "05:15:30";
    String[] tokens1 = source1.split(":");
    int secondsToMs1 = Integer.parseInt(tokens1[2]) * 1000;
    int minutesToMs1 = Integer.parseInt(tokens1[1]) * 60000;
    int hoursToMs1 = Integer.parseInt(tokens1[0]) * 3600000;
    int total1 = secondsToMs1 + minutesToMs1 + hoursToMs1;
```

Luego agrego otra hora:

```
    String source12 = "03:05:10";
    String[] tokens12 = source1.split(":");
    int secondsToMs12 = Integer.parseInt(tokens12[2]) * 1000;
    int minutesToMs12 = Integer.parseInt(tokens12[1]) * 60000;
    int hoursToMs12 = Integer.parseInt(tokens12[0]) * 3600000;
    int total12 = secondsToMs12 + minutesToMs12 + hoursToMs12;
```

y calculo la suma de ambos:

```
Long t = new Long(total1) + new Long(total12);
```

Ahoras si yo muestro nuevamente el total en formato hh:mm:ss, la suma de ambos me muestra:

```
String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(t),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(t) % TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(1),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(t) % TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(1)); 


System.out.print(hms);
```

> 10:31:00

pero tendria que mostrarme un total de :

> 08:20:40

Comment: Te recomiendo echarle un vistazo a esta publicación https://stackoverflow.com/a/22230615/7064040

Comment: Convendría que repasaras los valores intermedios (calculando lo que tocaría salir a mano) para ver donde está el fallo, si en el cálculo de los milisegundos o en la conversión de vuelta a horas. Cuanto más pequeño es un problema, más fácil es encontrar la solución.

Comment: Aparte (y estoy ya es más una opinión personal), escribir `TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(1)` en vez de `60` solo complica la legibilidad del código; está muy bien evitar "números mágicos" cuando pueden variar, pero una hora siempre van a ser 60 minutos.

Comment: Y por último, `Long t = new Long(total1) + new Long(total2)` crea montones de objetos innecesarios (con *autoboxing* y *autounboxing*). `Long t = total1 + total2;` es perfectamente válido, más eficiente y legible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creo que hacer copypaste te ha jugado una mala pasada:

```
String[] tokens12 = source1.split(":");
```

debería ser:

```
String[] tokens12 = source12.split(":");
```